# React Native onPress gets called on every component rendered by mapping json

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-native

I tried Googling this but due to the English language not being my greatest skill I find it hard to Google the right thing. I've tried to fix this problem myself which works, but I wonder if there are better ways to do this.

**Situation:**

I have a json object and want to render the values in it, so I mapped the values and render it in a component. I only have to call that component once and it will render itself multiple times acoording to how many objects are in my json object.

Now when I fire the onPress function on a single, specific rendered instance, it will fire for every rendered instance.

**Desired situation:**

When I have multiple rendered instances of my component, and I fire onPress on a single one, it should only fire for that instance.

**Code:**

I'm performing a get request and response returns a json object:

```
{
"objects": [
    {
        "name": "Alarm chauffeurs@ON=100",
        "object_id": 1,
        "input_value": 0,
        "last_changed": "2019-03-08T14:30:54",
    }, ...
```

Next I map the values to my component:

```
      let cards = this.state.dataSource.objects.map((val, key) => {
      return (
         <Animated.View key={key} style={[cardStyle.container, { height: this.state.collapse[parseInt(val.object_id)] }]}>
            <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.toggle(val.object_id)} />
         </Animated.View>
      );
      });
```

Now I have to call `{cards}` in my MainView only once and React Native will render multiple cards:

```
      return (
         <View style={style.container}>
            <View style={style.colDash}>
               <ScrollView>
                  {cards}
               </ScrollView>
            </View>
        </View>
      );
```

[Here's an image of the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjgBK.jpg)

Now once I press a button, onPress gets fired on every component on screen.

**I've tried:**

Created an array and pushed a random value to it as `id` always starts at 1. The rest is done with a simple for loop. This probably isn't the best way to handle my problem.

```
  toggle(id) {
     var test = []
     test.push(123);
     for (var i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
         if (id == i) {
             var temp = new Animated.Value(75);
             Animated.timing(
                temp, {
                   toValue: 150,
                   duration: 500,
                }
             ).start()
             test.push(temp);
         }
         else {
             var temp = new Animated.Value(75);
             Animated.timing(
                temp, {
                    toValue: 75,
                    duration: 1,
                }
             ).start()
             test.push(temp);
        }
     }
     this.setState({
         collapse: test
      });
```

Later on, I also want to add the possibility to be able to toggle multiple instances at the same time. As of now when I fire one onPress, the rest gets reset.

Answer (score 0):

Add an index to your TouchableHighlight component and try then

Comment: Sorry, how would I go about doing this?

Comment: Yes add a key, the onPress handler doesn't recognize which element you clicked.

something like key={key + '-highlight}